# Difference between Customer.search and Customer.find in Shopify API gem?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I wanted to get email addresses of all customers who have bought our "foobar" products. First I tried this. It worked pretty fine.

```
Customer.search(query: "state:enabled").each do |c|
  c.orders.map do |o| 
    o.line_items.each do |i| 
      t = i.title
      p c.email if t.include?("foobar")
    end 
  end
end
```

Then I tried another way, which I thought is equivalent to the above one. But this one only resulted in a subset of the above.

```
Customer.find(:all, params:{state:"enabled"}).each do |c|
  c.orders.map do |o| 
    o.line_items.each do |i| 
      t = i.title
      p c.email if t.include?("foobar")
    end 
  end
end
```

My question is; What is the difference between `Customer.search(...)`, the endpoint of `/admin/customers/search.json`, and `Customer.find(:all, ...)`?

edit: I have more than 50 (the default limit of the number of returned values) customers of "foobar" products, so each of them actually is a subset of the whole set of customers satisfying the query. But the both query would be the same result, if there is no difference between `Customer.search` and `Customer.find`. Or, am I guessing wrong here??